# Can I delete MEMORY.DMP file from my laptop

Tags: windows-10, disk-cleanup, hp-laptop

I have `HP laptop` with `Windows 10`. I have seen there is a file in `C:\Windows` folder `MEMORY.DMP` with size almost 7.33GB.

Can I delete this file permanently from my laptop ? or will it create any problem ?

[image]

Comment: Yes you can delete those. No that won't create any problem unless you need that .DMP file to analyse a BSOD https://www.howtogeek.com/196672/windows-memory-dumps-what-exactly-are-they-for/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP` file was probably created on 28-07-2021 after your Windows 10 system crashed. It should be safe to remove (unless you are interested in analyzing that old crash).

An 8 GB system RAM would explain its size.

Read up more on this around the [Complete Memory Dump](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/complete-memory-dump) Microsoft documentation pages.